# Add dependencies of shinydashboardplus in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, htmltools, shinydashboardplus

Below is the code for shiny app that I am using.

```
shiny::shinyApp(fluidPage(    
  
  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Telephones by region"),
  
  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      
    
    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("region", "Region:", 
                  choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
      hr(),
      helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")
    ),
    
    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("phonePlot")  
    )
    
  )
),

# Define a server for the Shiny app
function(input, output) {
  
  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
    
    # Render a barplot
    barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
            main=input$region,
            ylab="Number of Telephones",
            xlab="Year")
  })
})
```

Now I am trying to add dependencies of `shinydashboardplus` using `htmltools` and use the `box()` from `shinydashboardplus`. Something like the below image taken from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinydashboardPlus/vignettes/improved-boxes.html.

[image]

How could I add the dependencies of shinydashboardplus to this simple shiny app?